# How to check if values of two hashes are equal?

Tags: perl

I have to check if the values of two hashes are equal...

hash 1: `19261 | 9;0;9;0;1`
hash 2: `19261 | 9;0;9;0;1`

if a value in hash 1 or two is not equal like:

hash 1: `19261 | 9;0;9;0;1`
hash 2: `19261 | 9;0;9;0;5`

it should appear an error!!!

I did it this way:

```
if($ADL_HNO{"$LinkID;$NameIndex;$Side"} == $ADLT_HNO{"$key[0];$key[1];$key[2]"} ){
   #print " HNO identisch\n";
}
else
{
   print "Die ADL-HNO: ".$ADL_HNO{"$LinkID;$NameIndex;$Side"}."\ mit der LinkID: $LinkID und Side: $Side sind nicht identisch zur ADLT-HNO: ".$ADLT_HNO{"$key[0];$key[1];$key[2]"}."\n";
}
```

At the moment it compares only the first number (in this case the 9).
How can i check all?

Comment: Use `eq` to compare strings. Are you using `use strict; use warnings;`?

Comment: ahh ok now it works....I used the wrong operator... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By using the numeric comparison operator (`==`) you are telling Perl to compare your values as numbers. And Perl is very happy to do that.

```
$ perl -E'say "19261 | 9;0;9;0;1" == "19261 | 9;0;9;0;5"'
1
```

If you had `use warnings` turned on (and you should always do that) then Perl would have told you:

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -E'say "19261 | 9;0;9;0;1" == "19261 | 9;0;9;0;5"'
Argument "19261 | 9;0;9;0;5" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
Argument "19261 | 9;0;9;0;1" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
1
```

When Perl is asked to compare strings as numbers, it looks for something that looks like a number at the start of the string and uses that (in this case, the value 19261). If no number is found, it uses a zero.

You can see how Perl will interpret your string as a number, by adding zero to it.

```
$ perl -E'say "19261 | 9;0;9;0;1" + 0'
19261
```

In short, if you want to compare strings, use the string comparison operators (in this case, `eq`).

And always `use warnings`!